# Cyclotomic polynomial : $\Phi_n(x^m)= \prod_{d\mid m} \Phi_{dn}(x)$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Show that if $m, n$ are positive integers and $\text{gcd} (m,n)=1$, then $$\Phi_n(x^m)= \displaystyle\prod_{d\mid m} \Phi_{dn}(x)$$

---

My attempt :

By formula, $x^n-1 = \displaystyle\prod_{d\mid n} \Phi_{d}(x)$

$x^n-1 - \displaystyle\prod_{d\mid n} \Phi_{d}(x) = 0$

$x^n-1 - \displaystyle\prod_{d\mid n} \Phi_{d}(x) + \Phi_{n}(x)= \Phi_{n}(x)$

$x^{nm}-1 - \displaystyle\prod_{d\mid n} \Phi_{d}(x^m) + \Phi_{n}(x^m)= \Phi_{n}(x^m)$

Please suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roots of $\Phi_n(z)$ are the primitive $n$-th roots of unity, hence every root of $\Phi_n(z^m)$ is a  $mn$-th root of unity and a *primitive* $kn$-th root of unity for some $k\mid m$. In other terms,
$$ \Phi_n(x^m)=\prod_{k\mid m}\Phi_{kn}(x).$$

Comment: Will you please explain more on this point, "every root of $\Phi_n(z^m)$ is a *primitive* $kn$-th root of unity for some $k\mid m$." ? Thank you.

Comment: @carat: every $mn$-th root of unity is a primitive root for some divisor of $mn$ which is a multiple of $n$. We are restating in analytic terms the Chinese remainder theorem, stating that $$\mathbb{Z}/(mn\mathbb{Z})^* \simeq \mathbb{Z}/(n\mathbb{Z})^* \times \mathbb{Z}/(m\mathbb{Z})^*.$$

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I do understand that it is quite straightforward to see that $\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{C}:\alpha$ is a root of $\Phi_n(x^m)$ if and only if $\alpha$ is a root of $\prod_{k\mid m}\Phi_{kn}(x)$. Moreover, it is easy to see that the degrees of the two polynomials are equal to $m\phi(n)$, using Gauss lemma (Sum of Euler Phi Function over Divisors). However, it is not sufficient as there might be roots with multiplicities and we need to show that the multiplicity of each root is the same in both of the polynomials, which is unclear to me...

Comment: @DonFanucci: it cannot happen. Cyclotomic polynomials are divisors of $x^m-1$, hence all their roots are simple.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah you are right! Thank U!

Comment: @JackD'aurizio It is not clear to me why it is a multiple of $n$ (though I understand algebraically why when I write it explicitly on paper) and I don't get why it reaches *all* of the multiples of $n$. The use of CRT goes over my head...

Comment: Ok I got a proof of your claim but it is still highly non-trivial to me

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula
$$X^N-1 = \prod_{d \mid N} \Phi_d(x)$$

so
$$X^{Nm}-1 = \prod_{d \mid N} \Phi_d(x^m)$$

But we can also write

$$X^{Nm}-1 = \prod_{d \mid N m } \Phi_d(x)$$

Now assume that $(N,d) = 1$. Then every divisor $d$ of $Nm$ can be written uniquely as $d = d_1 d_2$, with $d_1 \mid N$ and $d_2 \mid m$. Therefore we get

$$X^{Nm}-1 = \prod_{ d_1 \mid N, d_2 \mid m} \Phi_{d_1 d_2}(x)$$
and so

$$\prod_{d_1 \mid N}\Phi_{d_1}(x^m) =\prod_{d_1 \mid N, d_2 \mid m} \Phi_{d_1 d_2}(x) = \prod_{d_1 \mid N} \left( \prod_{d_2 \mid m} \Phi_{d_1 d_2}(x) \right) $$

We now can prove by induction on $n$ relatively prime to $m$, that

$$\Phi_{n}(x^m) = \prod_{d_2 \mid m} \Phi_{n d_2}(x)$$